# Simulating simple System verilog mailbox code using ModelSim

Tags: system-verilog

I was trying a basic mailbox code using Modelsim Student Version. I was able to compile the code successfully and simulate it, but I am not getting the expected result. There is a `for` loop inside the `put` and `get` tasks, but the loop is not getting executed.

```
// simple mailbox // 
module mailbox_new(); 
   mailbox my_mailbox; 
   initial begin 
    my_mailbox =new(); 
    if(my_mailbox) 
      begin 
      fork 
      put_packets(); 
      get_packets(); 
      #1000; 
      join_any 
      end 
      #1000; 
      $display("END OF PROGRAM"); 
   end 

  task put_packets(); 
   integer i; 
   begin 
   for(i=0;i<10;i++); 
    begin 
    #10; 
    my_mailbox.put(i); 
    $display("Done putting packet %d @time %d",i, $time); 
    end 
    end 
   endtask 

 task get_packets(); 
  integer j; 
  begin 
  for(j=0;j<10;j++); 
   begin 
   #10; 
   my_mailbox.get(j); 
   $display("Done getting packet %d @time %d",j, $time); 
   end 
  end 
 endtask 
 endmodule
```

The result being displayed is:

```
  # Done putting packet 10 @time 10 
  # Done getting packet 10 @time 10 
  # END OF PROGRAM
```

My `for` loop is not getting executed properly.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things wrong with your code, but the most obvious one is that you put a semicolon `;` after the `for` statements. This means you'll loop and not do anything and then execute the `begin...end` block. Remove the extra `;`s and you should be fine.